# SQL Simple Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have not used SQL in a while and really need some help.

Query 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = '_billing_dob'
```

[image]

Query 2:

```
SELECT `meta_value` 
FROM `postmeta` 
WHERE `post_id` = '131543' 
AND `meta_key` = '_billing_email'
```

[image]

Now I need to make the `post_id` in Query 2 to loop through all the `post_id` found in Query 1.

I need 2 columns with `meta_value` from Query 2 (email) and `meta value` from Query 1 (date of birth)

I just need to join these two queries basically. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Edit (This is the table which contains the email address):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6iwr.jpg

Both Values are in the same table and thats all the columns I have here

Comment: Can you show us some more sample table data _and also the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: your table2_email doesn't have primary key

Comment: You need to post table description for `postmeta`

Comment: I added a screenshot which contains a full view of Query 2 but where I select * columns